# ng-model runs all the watchers in the entire page

Tags: angularjs

Our application is huge which has minimum 10,000 two binding.I have checkbox which is binding to the scope model. so i don't want to run all watcher on value change of checkbox. Currently on value change it's run all watcher when check with AngularJS Batarang tool.
[Angular Batarang Screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bNyr.png)

Is there any to digest to particular scope without running entire watcher?

Comment: You can add one-way data binding from AngularJS 1.4+, I'm not sure if this is a viable option in your case.

Comment: You can watch more specific: $scope.watch("yourbinding", ...

Comment: #Sphaso one way binding is the one of the option but i need two binding. content change dynamically